# How to Make Index Recognize an Exclamation Point as Part of an Entry

Tags: indexing, syntax, imakeidx, makeindex, grammar

I would like to add an entry in an index which makes use of an exclamation point as an article of grammar. However (of course), Latex treats it as if I want to begin a subentry.

Consider the following code.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
\makeindex
\usepackage{idxlayout}

\begin{document}
\LARGE
A sentence.\index{Heading@\textbf{Heading}!How to put an exclamation point at the end of this statement!}
\idxlayout{columns=1}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

with the output

[image]

I have tried enclosing the exclamation point with `$$` but that only yields an error.

QUESTION How may the above code be modified so that, for instance, "How to put an exclamation point at the end of this statement!" will appear as an entry in the index with the exclamation point appended at the end?

Thank you.

Comment: `"!` for the exclamation mark that you want to appear as such in the index.

Comment: Many thanks @egreg.

Comment: in addition to the above comment all of the special characters are customisable. If you want to use a different character for subentry your makeindex style can specify that.

Comment: @David Carlisle Sorry for the delay in my response. Are you saying that I could redefine a command to replace `!` for starting a new subentry; and then obviate the need to use `"!` thereafter when I want an exclamation point as part of the content? If so, can you direct me to where I can learn how to do this---or would you suggest I ask this as a new question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can quote the `!` as `"!`

or you can change makeindex's special characters all of which may be set in a `makeindex` style.
for example the `gind.ist` that comes with the LaTeX base `doc` package has

```
actual '='
quote '!'
level '>'
```

so that `actual` is `=` not `@` (as there are lots of `@` in command names) and quote is `!` rather than `"` again as `"` is rather more common in code.

The full set is

[image]

from makeindex/ind.pdf

`texdoc ind.pdf`

(`texdoc -l makeindex` then select 2 as the default makeindex.pdf isn't so informative)

So here you want

[image]

so a one line `mlc.ist` file:

```
level '>'
```

So that `!` becomes a normal character and `>` becomes the index level separator.

If calling `makeindex` directly you would need `makeindex -s mlc.ist` but as you are using `imakeidx` specify the option to `\makeindex`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
\makeindex[options=-s mlc.ist]
\usepackage{idxlayout}

\begin{document}
\LARGE
A sentence.\index{Heading@\textbf{Heading}>How to put an exclamation point at the end of this statement!}
\idxlayout{columns=1}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for posting this, but I do not understand it. Perhaps you would kindly incorporate something from it in the MWE so I can visualize it. In your earlier comment, it sounded to me that one could replace `!` by some other symbol in order to effect a sub-entry. If this is correct, perhaps you would modify the MWE to show this.

Comment: @mlchristians yes that's what gind.ist that I show does it uses > instead of ! as `level` use as `makeindex -s gind.ist yourfile`

Comment: @mlchristians example added

Comment: Many thanks @David Carlisle.